# Represent multiple Null/Generic objects in an ActiveRecord association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, belongs-to

I have a Casefile model that belongs_to a Doctor. In additional to all the "real" doctors, there are several generic Doctors: "self-treated", "not specified", and "removed" (it used to have a real doctor, but no longer does). I suspect there will be even more generic values in the future.

I started with special "doctors" in the database, generated from seed. The generic Doctors only need to respond to the `name, title, company, published?` methods.

This worked with one, was strained with two, and now feels completely broken. I want to change the behavior and can't figure out how to test it, a bad sign. Creating all the generic objects for testing is also trouble, including fake values to pass validation of the required Doctor attributes.

The Null Object pattern works well for one generic object. The "name" method could return "self-treated", as demonstrated by [Craig Ambrose](http://www.craigambrose.com/blog/2006/09/22/active-record-associations-and-the-null-object-pattern/).

What pattern should I use when there are multiple generic objects with very limited state?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you could just add an extra field to the Casefile model called, say, `treatment` (which would be set to "self-treated", "not specified" etc.)

You could add a validation to ensure a Casefile either has a doctor or treatment assigned:

```
validate :has_doctor_or_treatment, :on => :save

def has_doctor_or_treatment
  (self.doctor.exists? || !treatment.blank?)
end
```

Then you could use the treatment field to find Casefile's using `.where`:

```
Casefile.where(:treatment => "self-treated")
```

If you wanted, you could have treatment as an extra model, where Casefile `has_one` Doctor and `has_one` Treatment - but it seems like your needs are too simple to warrant that.